# Load testing PowerBI reports with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, powerbi, performance-testing, load-testing

Looking for inputs from experts who have experience in load testing PowerBI reports.

I tried to capture traffic using Fiddler and Developer Tools on edge, but I don't see the main URL's like https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/apps (PowerBI HomePage -> Apps) in them.

What are the other ways to do load testing for PowerBI reports?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Power BI security white paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-powerbi-security)

> **Which communication protocols are used by the on-premises data gateway, and how are they secured?**
>
> - The gateway supports the following two communications protocols:
>
>   - AMQP 1.0 – TCP + TLS: This protocol requires ports 443, 5671-5672, and 9350-9354 to be open for outgoing communication. This protocol is preferred, since it has lower communication overhead.
>   - HTTPS – WebSockets over HTTPS + TLS: This protocol uses port 443 only. The WebSocket is initiated by a single HTTP CONNECT message. Once the channel is established, the communication is essentially TCP+TLS. You can force the gateway to use this protocol by modifying a setting described in the on-premises gateway article.

As per [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) name suggests it can record only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) protocols. If your system under test uses other protocols you will need to identify what are they using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and use a suitable [JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) which supports these protocols.